# for each loop post only one record with php

Tags: php, mysql

good evening everyone, i have a for each loop in php that post only one record to database table.
my html code below;

```
<html>
<input type="hidden" name="username[]" value="<?php echo $userRow['username']; ?>" readonly />
<input type="hidden" name="school[]" value="<?php echo $userRow['school']; ?>" readonly />
<SELECT name='cand_name[]' class='form-control'>
<option></option>
<option>Ahmed MUSA</option>
<option>Ahmed Arinze</option>
<option>NOsa Igiebor</option>
</SELECT>
<SELECT name='cand_name[]' class='form-control'>
<option></option>
<option>Ahmed MUSA</option>
<option>Ahmed Arinze</option>
<option>NOsa Igiebor</option>
</SELECT>
</html>
```

code below;

```
<?php
include_once 'dbcon.php';

{
$username = $_POST['username'];
    $cand_name = $_POST['cand_name'];
        $school = $_POST['school'];

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($username); $i++) {

        $username = ($username[$i]);
        $cand_name = ($cand_name[$i]);
        $school = ($school[$i]);

        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO parlia (username, cand_name, school) VALUES ('$username', '$cand_name', '$school')");
    } 
}
```

i hav checked other SO answers but none seem to work for me.
i have edited and it still doesn't work. when i tried this code with input, it worked perfectly but doesn't want to work with options

Comment: what is in the $_POST['username']?

Comment: How many items are in `$_POST['username']` etc? Can you do `var_dump($_POST['username'])`?

Comment: We need information to solve your 'problem'. So far I don't see any problem yet. For example, start with explaning what your problem is and for example, what's the size of $username?

Comment: Show the HTML/PHP code that sends data. I believe you sending only one username, cand_name, school packet.

Comment: First `$username` is array. WIth `$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username[$i]);` $username is __overwritten__

Comment: jjust added the html.. what happens is that only one record gets posted into the database. also done wat u_mulder suggested but its still nt woring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this piece of code works for me.. you are however susceptible to sql injection

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'][0];
    $school = $_POST['school'][0];
        $candname = $_POST['candname'];
            foreach ($_POST['candname'] as $candname) {
     $query = sprintf(
            "INSERT INTO parlia_votes (username, school, candname) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')",
            $username,
            $school,
            $candname
        );
        $con->query($query);
    }
?>
```

Comment: thx a lot.. this worked for me too.. but kindly xplain what you did sir

Answer (score 0):

Where are `<?php echo $userRow['username']; ?>` and `<?php echo $userRow['school']; ?>` coming from? this are coming from fields in the dbase table.. only logged in users are to have access to the page i'm workin on

Comment: Are these coming from the parlia database table?

Comment: i wish to post details of the logged in user into new parlia tbl for verification

Comment: Okay so username and school are the logged in user's credentials?

Comment: Can you show me the script in your question that pulls the values from the logged in credentials database? Please leave out any connection data.

Comment: session_start();
include_once 'dbcon.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
//if (isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
?>
<script> window.location("index.php"); </script>
<?php
   //header("Location: index.php");
}
$res=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM students WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
?>